# cytoscape.js multiple instances on page

Tags: javascript, graph, cytoscape.js

I am having trouble having two instances of cytoscape setup on same webpage. I have two window vars "cy" and "cy2" that are being used for different graphs. They are functionally different graphs and need to be available on different parts of the page. I wanted to know how to get that setup correctly?

When I look at page elements, the one not showing has the width and height of the underlying canvases set to 0 by cytoscape.js. Can you please help me to understand what is being initialized wrong or how these values can get set like that.

Thanks
gmania

[chrome dev tool screen of cytoscape.js element div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bN2KI.png)

Comment: Found the answer...did not include a CSS style for the second graph in the page markup. Just in case someone else has run into this issue!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the multiple instances demo: http://js.cytoscape.org/demos/310dca83ba6970812dd0

Also make sure you set dimensions properly in your CSS for each container.  If you specify a div with zero size, then the internal Cy canvases will match.